# Smarty Object Function with Associative Array Unexpected "=>", expected one of: "","" , ")"'

Tags: php, pdo, smarty

I am having a problem with Smarty passing a PDO Object to Smarty it just doesn't like `=>`. Is there a trick to get around this problem?

Here is he error:

```
{assign var='brgdatas' value="{$brgObj->fetchOneBrg(array('id'=>{$ststres[ststval].to_id}'))}"}" - Unexpected "=>", expected one of: "","" , ")
```

Here is the code I am working with:

```
{section name=ststval loop=$ststres}

{if $ststres[ststval].type == 2}

{assign var='brgdatas' value="{$brgObj->fetchOneBrg(array('id'=>{$ststres[ststval].to_id}'))}"}
```

The correct answer Update:

Is to add [] between the associative array and remove the quotes like so.

```
{assign var='brgdatas' value=$brgObj->fetchOneBrg(['id'=>$ststres[ststval].to_id])}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the last single apostrophe and the keys `{}` inside the `value` attribute

```
value="{$brgObj->fetchOneBrg(array('id'=>{$ststres[ststval].to_id}'))}"
       ^                                 ^                        ^  ^
```

Comment: Yes sir. `"{assign var='bragdatas' value="{$bragObj->fetchOneBrag(array('id'=>{$ststres[ststval].to_id}))}"}" - Unexpected "=>"`

Comment: Remove the set of keys `{}` inside `'id'=>`.

Comment: No change, here is the new code. `{assign var='brgdatas' value="{$brgObj->fetchOneBrg(array('id'=>$ststres[ststval].to_id))}"}`

Comment: Then try the set of keys `{}` inside `value=""`. _That_ should do it!

Comment: That worked!!! Thank you! However, now I am this error `Catchable fatal error: Object of class users_class could not be converted to string in on line 263` This line is the same object which I am returning it like this `return $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` is this correct?