# __toString() must return a string value

Tags: php, object, tostring

Can someone tell me what I am doing wrong? This is my first time using __toString. I receiving the follwoing error: `Catchable fatal error: Method users_class::__toString() must return a string value`

This is my call to the object using Smarty:

```
 {assign var='udatas' value="$userObj->fetchUser(array('id'=>$ststres[ststval].to_id))"}
```

This is the object.

```
class users_class {

protected $users_class;

public function __toString() {

    return $this->users_class;
}
  public function fetchUser(array $conditions){
            $db = Core::getInstance();

            $sql = "SELECT * FROM ".USERS." WHERE ";
            $i=0;
            $params = array();
            //$where = array();
            foreach ($conditions as $column => $value) {
            if (preg_match('/^[a-z-.-_]+$/', $column)) {
                if($i!=0){
                    $sql .= " AND ";
                }
            $sql .= "$column = ?";
            $params[] = $value;
            $i++;

    }
   }            
            //$sql .= implode(' AND ', $where);
            //$sql .= " order by title asc";    
            $res = $db->dbh->prepare($sql);
            $res->execute(array_values($params));
            return $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);               
}   
   }
```

Comment: Fix to `protected $users_class = '';` or `return (string)$this->users_class;`

Comment: It means that whatever value you have set to the variable `$users_class` is not a string.

Comment: What type of value should be stored in `users_class`?

Comment: Why are you trying to implement `__toString()` to begin with?

Comment: @Glavic after incorporating your suggestion it resolved the error but the fuction does not return the desired result. I think it just surpresses error.

Comment: @Jan-Henk I know what it means but do you resolve it.

Comment: @PeeHaa I am trying to implement this because `{assign var='udatas' value="$userObj->fetchUser(array('id'=>$ststres[ststval].to_id))"}` was throwing this error. `Catchable fatal error: Object of class could not be converted to string`

Comment: @Glavić also after implementing your suggestion the out is this `string(46) "->fetchUser(array('id'=>Array[ststval].to_id))` instead of the desired output. do you or anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You will have to remove the double quotes around the smarty `value=` assignment :  `{assign var='udatas' value=$userObj->fetchUser(array('id'=>$ststres[ststval].to_id))}`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The error message `... must return a string value ...` just means the return value of __toString() has to be a value of data type string. If $users_class in your example is not intended to be a string value, it has be to converted to a string before returning it.

But when reading the above example, it seems to me that the var $users_class may just not have been initialized yet. In this case change the method __toString() to :

```
public function __toString() {
    if(is_null($this->users_class)) {
        return 'NULL';
    }
    return $this->user_class;
}
```

To make the above code working, you'll need to make a change in the smarty code too. Remove the double quotes around the value of the `value=` attribute.

Comment: Or return `get_class($this)` in the `__toString()` method.

Comment: @hek2mgl after implementing your suggestion the output is this string(46) "->fetchUser(array('id'=>Array[ststval].to_id)) instead of the desired output. It seems that the only thing it accomplished was suppressing the error. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: You will have to remove the double quotes around the smarty `value=` assignment :  `{assign var='udatas' value=$userObj->fetchUser(array('id'=>$ststres[ststval].to_id))}`

Comment: @hek2mgl after removing the quotes I receive the following error `{assign var='udatas' value=$userObj->fetchUser(array('id'=>$ststres[ststval].to_id))}" - Unexpected "=>", expected one of: "","" , ")"`

Comment: This is a smarty syntax problem and not related to the title of this question. I would suggest that you open a separate question for it.

Comment: @hek2mgl prior to this I opened a question regarding smarty syntax which was resolved [Smarty Question Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13894472/smarty-object-function-with-associative-array-unexpected-expected-one-of) which lead me here

Comment: @hek2mgl the correct way to do it is to add [] between the associative array in smarty like so. 
`{assign var='brgdatas' value=$brgObj->fetchOneBrg(array(['id'=>$ststres[ststval].to_id]))}`

Comment: PHP 7+ Supports `return $this->users_class ?? 'NULL';`. For future viewers

Comment: @Jaquarh `if($this->user_class)` is not the same as `if(is_null($this->user_class))`

Comment: I didn't say it was, I said PHP 7+ supports `??` operator if they want to check the variable is first set since a call to `__toString() { return $this->someProperty; }` throws an Error if you don't check it is either `is_null()` like your answer states which is good or `isset()` - Just a tool for future viewers to be able to use too

Comment: I'm just saying `return $this->users_class ?? 'NULL';` would return `'NULL'` even if `$this->user_class` has a value of `false, 0, "", []`

Answer (score 2):

just replace with: 
**return (string)$this->user_class;**

Answer (score 0):

You are using `$res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` which will return any array.
You are accessing the values as a standard object.
You need to cast to a class, you might try using the `PDO::FETCH_CLASS` instead of the `FETCH_ASSOC`.

It's hard to say with the code that you have included.

Comment: @Kevin after changing to PDO::FETCH_CLASS I received the following error `Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: No fetch class specified`

Comment: You would need to add the class name users_class as the first column of your SQL.  So that would be SELECT 'users_class', * FROM.  You could also use FETCH_OBJ but that would return a StdClass and you would not get your __toString function called